# onclick not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script which expands an accordion menu when clicked.
I select the required menu item by using getElementsByClassName

```
window.onload = function() {
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
 //  var acc = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion_f");
 var i; 

// test code start
 acc[10].classList.toggle("active");
 acc[10].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
// test code end

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function(){
//        acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
   this.classList.toggle("active");
//        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
   }
 }
};
```

Unfortunately the onclick will not trigger, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I tested the getElementsByClassName by using

```
acc[10].classList.toggle("active");
acc[10].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
```

This works correctly so getElementsByClassName is working
I also tried using document.querySelectorAll this also worked

I tried using this and acc[i] neither seemed to work. But I sense this is not the problem as when I inspect the html elements and check Events, I see no event handlers registered on the current element.

my html looks like this:

```
<button class="accordion_f">24/7 Activity Tracking</button>
<div class="panel">
      <p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>
```

So in summary why does this work:

```
 acc[10].classList.toggle("active");
 acc[10].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
```

But this does not work or even register on elements

```
   acc[i].onclick = function(){
```

**UPDATE**

My accordion menu is inside a Tab menu which has it's own JavaScript to change tabs:

```
var newHTML = document.getElementById(newTab).innerHTML;
document.getElementById('first_View').innerHTML = newHTML;
```

I moved the accordion menu outside the Tab menu and onclick works. 
If I comment out the above code from the tab menu script, my accordion menu works, but then the Tab menu will not change.

Further testing using addEventListener instead of onclick:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
  var i; 

// test code start
  acc[10].classList.toggle("active");
  acc[10].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
// test code end

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener('click', expand_m, false); 
  } 
};  

function expand_m(){      
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This does exactly the same as the original onclick code above, when I inspect the html elements and check Events, I see no event handlers registered on the current element, so clicking does not work for me, unless I stop the innerHTML changes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a `elem.toggle()` method in vanilla JS? Either I'm ignorant or it really doesn't exist. Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: @DanielCheung As a matter of fact, [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), except it's a method for a an element's classList, not the element itself.

Comment: @xorspark Hey thanks! My Google searches were flooded with jQuery results. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the embedding my javascript in another menu, the javascript from the tab menu was overwriting my accordion menu javascript.

So I simply called the accordion function at the end of the Tab menu and the onclicks started working.

```
function changeTab(tab){        
var newTab = "view"+tab;
var element_id = "t";
var newHTML = document.getElementById(newTab).innerHTML;  
document.getElementById('first_View').innerHTML = newHTML; 

accord_menu();         
}

function accord_menu() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
  var i; 

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give a refrence of `i` to your function that occurs onclick:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");

  for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = (function(index) {
      return function() {
        acc[index].classList.toggle("active");
        acc[index].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    })(i);
  };
};
```

```css
.accordion_f {
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion_f">24/7 Activity Tracking</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion_f">24/7 Activity Tracking</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion_f">24/7 Activity Tracking</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You also need to return a function, otherwise this will just execute the code for each iteration.

Comment: @xorspark, Tanx, Edited ;)

Comment: This still does not work, when I inspect the html elements and check Events, I see no event handlers registered on the current element.

My accordion menu is inside a tab menu which has it's own css classes, so I moved the accordion menu outside the tab menu and onclick works.

So can css prevent onclick working on a specific class?

I am not using any id's and my class names are unique.

Comment: Run above code snippet and you can see it works fine. please update your question with related html, css, and js without them we cant help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I don't understand the need for function(index) and return function() .

My code runs fine without it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
 //  var acc = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion_f");
 var i; 


 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function(){
//        acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
   this.classList.toggle("active");
//        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
   }
 }
  });
```

```html
<button class="accordion_f">24/7 Activity Tracking</button>
<div class="panel">
      <p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>
```